Securing snmptrapd.conf Credentials and Understanding Potential Risks
I am working in an offline RHEL environment and am looking for a way to secure the snmptrapd.conf file to prevent credentials from being stored in plain text while ensuring the snmptrapd service continues to operate seamlessly.
While I understand that SNMP v3 provides encryption for transmitted traps, my primary concern is about securing the credentials stored within the snmptrapd.conf file itself.
Could anyone share best practices, tools, or methods to achieve this?
Additionally, I’d like to understand the potential risks of a leaked SNMP trap password. From my understanding, the trap password is primarily used to decrypt traps sent from a server. Beyond being able to access the transmitted trap data, what other risks could this pose?
